# How can I find pid of my PHP job on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, pid

I have created several PHP (CLI) services. To get their PID from another process in the best way.

However, I can not find this solution optimal..

Comment: Do you mean something like [getmypid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The question states "from another process".

Answer (score 0):

Don't `grep` the output of `ps`. Instead, use `pgrep`. If you only have one PHP processes running, you can find the processes by its name as follows:

```sh
pgrep php;
```

and it will return something like `49282`.

However, since you stated that there are several ones running, you can differentiate between them using `pgrep --full`. For example, if you are running 2 commands, `php foo.php` and `php bar.php`, and you want the PID of the process running `foo.php`:

```sh
pgrep --full '^php foo\.php$'
```

While the `^` and `$` may not be necessary in all cases, they prevent false-positive matches. For more info on regular expressions, see [this `grep`-specific documentation](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html).

Answer (score -1):

If i don't get it wrong, the following code will work for you.

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Comment: I changed `grep php` to `grep p[h]p`. So the command doens't find itself.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to remember the PIDs after creating the the sub processes. All variants analyzing the complete process list may result in wrong positives.

Another solution is, to find/remember the process, who started the sub processes and search the child processes.

Anyway, you gave us to less details to help more specific.